# SQL Azure Firewall not used IP

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

Is there a way to determine which firewall IP's have not been used for certain amount of time to log in to sql azure ? I have few IP's and would like to delete the unused ones.

Comment: What op means over is he has whitelisted set of ip's for the sql azure. Now she wants to remove unused ips which are whitelisted. Op, please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have logging enabled you can check which firewall has been used for certain period, like it is used in last  months. Please see [fire wall logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/tutorial-diagnostics).

Azure Sql, as per my understanding does [not have any ip specific logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-metrics-diag-logging) and I am not able to find it.

For current sessions while there seems to be way to get client ip from sql server, [it does not seems to be available for Azure Sql](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/926f215b-6e0c-489e-83a0-22eced5c5732/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-in-sql-azure?forum=ssdsgetstarted).